# How can I get the next record date from a date and the last record date from a date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I create table Appointments with this structure:

```
  CREATE TABLE Appointments
    (
         [Id] bigint, 
         [Name] varchar(250),
         [DateInit] date
    );


INSERT INTO Appointments ([Id],  [Name],  [DateInit])
values 
(1000, 'Lorena', '03/06/2016'),
(1000, 'Lorena', '01/06/2016'),
(1000, 'Lorena', '08/06/2016'),
(1000, 'Lorena', '10/06/2016'),
(1000, 'Lorena', '02/06/2016'),
(1000, 'Lorena', '20/06/2016'),
(7000, 'Susan', '04/06/2016'),
(7000, 'Susan', '08/06/2016'),
(7000, 'Susan', '09/06/2016'),
(7000, 'Susan', '01/06/2016');
```

This is the final result:

[image]

I need to get the result for the next day and the day before, for example if today is '03/06/2016' I need to get result for the last appointment inserted in the table from today and the next appointment inserted in the table from today, the result I need is something like this:

```
   Name    Last Visit    Next Visit
    -----   ----------    -----------
   Lorena   2016-06-02    2016-06-08
   Susan    2016-06-01    2016-06-04
```

How can I get this result?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please also include the sample data in textual format?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I added the insert registers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `case` expressions to pick max previous appointment, and min future appointment:

```
select name,
       max(case when DateInit < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) then DateInit end) as LastVisit,
       min(case when DateInit > CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) then DateInit end) as NextVisit
from Appointments
group by name
```

Comment: CURRENT_DATE  = GETDATE() in MS SQL Server but it's on datetime. so just use CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) to just show the date.

Comment: @jarlh I get this error message, incorrect sytanx near 'min'

Comment: last visit instead of case Condition it will be much easier if we use MIN()

Comment: @Esraa_92, great to hear.

Comment: @Esraa_92 Note that for this to work `DateInit` must be always without timepart.

Comment: Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this as joins to the previous and next visit, something like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a.ID
    ,a.NAME
    ,l.LastVisit
    ,n.NextVisit
FROM Appointments a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,MIN(DateInit) NextVisit
    FROM Appointments
    WHERE DateInit > GETDATE()
    GROUP BY ID
    ) n ON a.ID = n.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,MAX(DateInit) LastVisit
    FROM Appointments
    WHERE DateInit < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY ID
    ) l ON a.ID = l.ID
```

Comment: Thank also for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE  @Appointments TABLE
    (
         [Id] bigint, 
         [Name] varchar(250),
         [DateInit] date
    );


INSERT INTO @Appointments ([Id],  [Name],  [DateInit])
values 
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/03'),
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/01'),
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/08'),
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/10'),
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/02'),
(1000, 'Lorena','2016/06/20'),
(7000, 'Susan', '2016/06/04'),
(7000, 'Susan', '2016/06/08'),
(7000, 'Susan', '2016/06/09'),
(7000, 'Susan', '2016/06/01');

DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE();

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT A.NAME
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID
            ) RN
        ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 DateInit
            FROM @Appointments B
            WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                AND DateInit < @TODAY
            ORDER BY DateInit DESC
            ) [Last Visit]
        ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 DateInit
            FROM @Appointments B
            WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                AND DateInit > @TODAY
            ORDER BY DateInit
            ) [Next Visit]
    FROM @Appointments A
        --GROUP BY ID
    )
SELECT C.NAME
    ,C.[Last Visit]
    ,C.[Next Visit]
    ,RN
FROM CTE C
WHERE RN = 1
```